# Installing dropbox on Debian 10: problem with libpango

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies, dropbox

I just install Debian 10 for the first time, and then dropbox, simply by downloading the `.deb` file and doing `dpkg -i`.

I got dropbox to run just fine, but unfortunately the install "broke" my `apt`, which keeps complaining:

```
dropbox : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.36.3) but it is not installable
```

Now it seems I cannot install new packages because of this. As far as I understand, this bug has been reported ([here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=956520)) and is due to a stupid reason, namely a renaming of the `libpango` package, which has not been updated in the dropbox deb.

What is the easiest solution for me to fix my system? (`apt --fix-broken install` will solve the issue by removing `dropbox`, but obviously I want to keep it.)

Comment: I see Dropbox deb is complied for Ubuntu, not Debian. So, if deb doesn't work, [compiling from source](https://www.dropbox.com/help/247) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most straightforward solution is to use the installer packaged in Debian non-free, rather than the package provided by Dropbox:

- remove the `dropbox` package;
- edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ensure that your `buster` lines include `contrib` and `non-free`, along the lines of

  ```
  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
  ```
- run `sudo apt update`;
- install `nautilus-dropbox`: `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`.

The `nautilus-dropbox` package uses [the source code provided by Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/247).

Answer (score 4):

I tried above solution but it didn't work to me. I'm using Debian 10. Then, I looked for another solution and found this. The solution below was copied from "https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/g13vxj/dropbox_users_in_testingsid_libpango100_to/".

**Dropbox users in Testing/Sid: libpango1.0-0 to libpango-1.0-0 removes Dropbox -- Here's a quick fix**

libpango1.0-0 is already gone in Testing so it cannot be upgraded and other packages report broken dependencies. If it is manually upgraded to libpango-1.0-0, Dropbox (an important package for me) is removed because it depends on the old package name.

It is possible Dropbox will release a fixed package soon but in the meantime it is very easy to fix the Dropbox deb file:

*Unpack deb file:*

`dpkg-deb -R dropbox_xyz.deb dir/`

*Edit* `dir/DEBIAN/control` *and change* `libpango1.0-0` *to* `libpango-1.0-0`

*Repackage in a new deb file:*

`dpkg-deb -b dir/ dropbox_xyz-fixed.deb`

*Install fixed Dropbox package.*

Install libpango-1.0-0 which will safely remove the old package and then upgrade everything else.

Comment: We do not like link-only answers here. Mainly because links can break. You should always provide the core information.

Comment: @eddiesaliba what are the changes of libpango?

Comment: @JorgeE.Cardona  I didn't check whether occurred internal modifcations in the library. But file's name was changed, like you can see above. Or, maybe, Dropbox's programmers made a mistake in configuration file. I don't know!

Comment: @eddiesaliba got it, I misread the name.